# How to replace a character in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to replace some of the list of lists by a specific word given by the user,I tried multiple times and kept getting an error and then after fixing the errors I have a code but the code wont print. Even though I typed print just so I could see how the code ran, nothing shows up.

Here is the list of lists:

```
table = [['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
        ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
        ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
        ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
        ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*']]
```

and here is the code I tried:

```
i = 0
def create_table(secret):

  secret = input("Enter the secret Word: ")
  secret = secret.upper()
  secret = secret.replace('J','I')
  return secret
  for row in range(5):
    for col in range(5):
        table = [t.replace(table[row][col], secret[i]) for t in table]
    i +=1
  print(table)
print(create_table(secret))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`table` is a mutable list, so just do:

```
table[row][col] = secret[i]
```

and remove the `return secret` or you won't get to the code.

A simple example:

```
import pprint

table = [['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
        ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
        ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
        ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
        ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*']]

def create_table():
    secret = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY'
    for row in range(5):
        for col in range(5):
            table[row][col] = secret[row*5 + col]
    pprint.pprint(table)

create_table()
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
 ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
 ['K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O'],
 ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T'],
 ['U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `return secret` half way through your function. This means that the remainder of the code in that function will not execute. You should move `return secret` to the end of the function definition.

You also are accepting a parameter to the `create_table()` function that you then immediately overwrite, you can get rid of this.

Comment: So I did that and to no surprise my code had an error: local variable table referenced before assignment. But I need table there, don't I?

Comment: you need to either declare it in the function, or say `global table` in the function so it knows to use it

Answer (score 0):

You have few problem with your code.

One thing to note is a function stops further execution once it returns something.*

So, In your function `create_table`, the lines after your return statement are not being executed at all.

Also note that, you either print from within the function or just return some value and print from the main body. You're printing from inside your function and also calling function as argument to print in main body.

Just do `return table` from your function and print from the main body. That's just the standard practice and right way to do it.
Or you don't even need to do that since you're modifying a global variable from inside your function anyway.

Edit: To modify the variable `table` from inside your function, add the line, 
`global table` within your function before you try to make any changes in `table` so that your function knows it's the global variable you're trying to modify and not creating a new local variable with the same name.

*I think there is a way to work around this.Not sure though.

Comment: But i declared it in the beginning, shouldn't that be enough since if it can not find the variable in the local code it looks at the next block of code?

Comment: You can just access a global variable from inside a function and can't modify it. See the edit in the answer.